# Android setText problem error with editText

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set a textview to a editText text. When I do that I have this error:

```
    Process: com.example.game, PID: 9829
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.game.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

It's strange because when I do system.out.println with the text I get

```
I/System.out: Player1
```

Can someone help me ?
My code:

```
        System.out.println(p1.getText().toString());
        System.out.println(p1.getEditableText().toString());
        j1.setText(p1.getEditableText().toString());
        j2.setText(p2.getEditableText().toString());
```

p1 and p2 are editText and j1 and j2 are TextView. I don't know if it's the problem but they are in different resource layout.

Comment: show full code please

Comment: Problem is that you said last line, they are in different resource layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your views are needed to be initialized after setting `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

However in your case you have them in different resource layout.

let's say you want to have views of `layout_xyz` in  `activity_main`.

in `activity_main`

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/xyzView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/layout_xyz" />
```

In `MainActivity.java`

initialize views from `layout_xyz`

```
View xyzView = findViewById(R.id.xyzView);

TextView j1FromXyz = xyzView.findViewById(R.id.j1);
TextView j2FromXyz = xyzView.findViewById(R.id.j2);
```

For more: [Re-using layouts with `<include/>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)

Comment: I'm gonna try thank you